# How to remove MediaItem after playing in Media3 ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3, exoplayer-media-item

I need callback that send event when was played ONE MediaItem (not all)
Something like "OnNextMediaItemPlayCallback"

I had tried to find callback, but find one only for ALL MEDIA HAS BEEN PLAYED.

I need to remove media item when media item was played.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/playlists#detecting-transitions
"hen playback transitions to another media item, or starts repeating the same media item, Listener.onMediaItemTransition(MediaItem, @MediaItemTransitionReason) is called"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the [detecting transitions documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/playlists#detecting-transitions):

> Then playback transitions to another media item, or starts repeating
> the same media item, Listener.onMediaItemTransition(MediaItem,
> @MediaItemTransitionReason) is called

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).